# unable to bind socket: Cannot assign requested address issue on ubuntu

Tags: networking, apt, 13.04

I can't update packages taken from the command `apt-get update` because after fetching the urls i get this error:

```
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up dnsproxy (1.16-0.1build1) ...
 * Starting dnsproxy dnsproxy unable to bind socket: Cannot assign requested address [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript dnsproxy, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing dnsproxy (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dnsproxy
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens while installing `apt-get install dnsproxy` package the configuration file `/etc/dnsproxy.conf` search `"# listen 192.168.168.1"` and comment the line or give your system ip address `"listen XX.XX.XX.XX"`
Then run `apt-get install -f` every thing should be fine.

May be this BUG ;-)